# Why does variable value reach 5050 after increment through two loops? (loop till 100)

Tags: c, loops, increment

I'm reading a beginners book on C programming and it has some exercises.
This is one of them, the question asked what would be the result of the following loop...

```
int main()
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {        
            result++;
        }
    }      

    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

my 'rational' answer would have been `1000`, but why is the correct answer `5050`?

Comment: A good idea would be to decrease 100 to say 5 and then use a debugger. Set watch points for i j and result

Comment: @sjsam a good idea would be to *derive a formula* for the answer.

Comment: @sjsam While I'd love to use the debugger for this, It's still very new to me. As I am, I can only use the debugger for checking 'where' seg faults happen and whatnot.

Comment: Gauss is famed for having solved this very question at age 7: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time, the inner loop will run once because `i` is `1`, adding `1` to `result`. The second time, it will run twice because `i` is `2`, adding `2` to `result` The third time, the inner loop will run thrice because `i` is `3`, adding `3` to `result`. And so on, until `100`.

Ultimately, this adds `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + … + 97 + 98 + 99 + 100` to `result`. This value is `5050`: the 100<sup>th</sup> triangle number.

If your compiler is smart (e.g. [`gcc -O2`](https://godbolt.org/z/MtUAsR)), it'll pick up on the fact that the innermost loop is simply an increment, and compile:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {        
        result++;
    }
}
```

to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    result += j;
}
```

If your compiler's *really* smart (e.g. [`clang -O2`](https://godbolt.org/z/eyRTL2)), it'll compile it to a simple `result = 5050;`, but such optimisations can end up being *really* slow to compile (it has to run the code beforehand to calculate what the value is meant to be, unless it special-cases specific examples which makes the compiler take up more space).

Answer (score 0):

@wizzwiss34's answer is correct ... adding a little more context.  In maths this is referred to as a [finite series](https://calculus.nipissingu.ca/tutorials/finiteseries.html) and what you are doing is implementing this mathematical function using C.

> A finite series is a summation of a finite number of terms. An
>   infinite series has an infinite number of terms and an upper limit of
>   infinity. This tutorial will deal with finite series. Infinite series
>   will be covered in the calculus tutorials.

In this case the sequence is 100+99+98+97...+1 = 5050

For the total number of `i`'s you add `i-1` each time.